# Provisional headers are shown in laravel + ionic

Tags: laravel, ionic-framework, ionic4

I'am using laravel + ionic.

my ionic is run on `localhost:8100`.
and my laravel is running on `myDomain/get/posts/comment`.
Iam using vagrant box for laravel.

my problem is when I access the `myDomain/get/posts/comment` throw browser, I got the response.
bu when I call this URL through ionic, response status code is `200`.

but showind `Provisional headers are shown`.

Please help me to solve this.

I searched on internet for solution, but couldn't solve.

Comment: I might have the cors issue..just ensure that.

Comment: No, I installed cors extension for chrome. and I didnt get any error about cors. can you tell me how can I check further to confirm whether it is cors issue or not?

Comment: Hey... just ensure at the laravel end the header contains `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: Thanks Bro. now its working. thanks a lot.

Comment: You are welcome! Glad to hear :)